# Parsing Status Code and Header in Ajax jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was trying to parse status code and Header in AJAX jQuery. The plan was to use the Location Header value to redirect when status code is 301. But, it seems parsing is not happening:

```
// Sign UP API
function Sign_up(email, pwd1, pwd2) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/v1/users/"+email+"/"+pwd1+"/"+pwd2, 
    type: 'POST',    
    dataType:"json",
  }).done(function(rs, textStatus, xhr) {
    alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
    alert(xhr.status);
  });
}
```

This signup function is called on a button click. I can see request going to server and proper status code and and Headers are returned. But no alert are shown on the webpage.

Comment: for headers do `xhr.getResponseHeader()`

Comment: Thanks this worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `statusCode` option:

Example from [`$.ajax docs`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. this works.. How can I put if else in status code? Also how to parse header..

Comment: Anything other than 200 series will go to error callbacks... add `.fail(function(jQxhr, status){ console.log(status)})`

Comment: Hi, I replied early after checking with other status code.. This however does not work with status code 301..

Comment: Actually,for some reason this does not work with status code 301, I had to return 200 from server and use success/error instead of status code,

Comment: use a 400 or 500 series if you want to add your own status error server side.